# URLs for goals when sign up page is on a subdomain

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Website:

- example.com

example.com Sign up complete page:

- secure.example.com/secure/thank_you?longstringhere

In Google Analytics (UA) I'd like to set up goals, where a person who sees the sign up page is a converted visitor.

From within the admin section of GA, when setting up goal details as a destination, I tested:

```
Destination Regular Expression: secure/common/callback
Destination URL equals: /secure/thank_you
Destination begins with: /secure/thank_you
When attempting to verify the result with all 3 variations the result is 0.
```

Is this because of the subdomain? It's all I can think of and I don't know how to change my regex to fit with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Destination Regular Expression: secure/thank_you.*
```